# Schwarz's theorem in any direction

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Schwarz's theorem says that if we have $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ twice continuously differentiable, then $\partial_l\partial_kf(x)=\partial_k\partial_lf(x)$ for all $l, k=1, \dots, n$, where $\partial_l f(x)$ denotes the partial derivative in the direction $e_i$ ($e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector).

Is it true that for all vectors $u, v\in\mathbb R^n$, $\partial_u\partial_vf(x)=\partial_u\partial_vf(x)$, not just for the elements of the standard basis?

Comment: yes it is. The point is that the Fréchet derivatives of $f$ are symmetric multilinear forms, this means that $\partial^n f(x)[y_1,\ldots ,y_n]=\partial^n f(x)[y_{\sigma (1)},\ldots ,y_{\sigma (n)}]$ for any chosen permutation $\sigma $ of $n$ elements. In particular $\partial_v\partial_w f(x)=\partial^2 f(x)[w,v]$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\partial_u f = \sum_{i=1}^n u^i \partial_i f$ where $u^i$ are the components of the vector $u$ along the basis $e_i$, namely $u=\sum_{i=1}^n u^i e_i$.